# Set path in Ext Js - TypeError: Ext.example is undefined

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a file from Ext.example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986519/how-to-use-a-file-from-ext-example)

I am using the `Ext.example.msg('Button Click', 'GOT SOME THING');` message box (Pop up box that appears on top of the screen). But i am getting this error message;

```
TypeError: Ext.example is undefined
```

In my app.js i have added the following code;

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.examples', 'app/extjs/examples/shared/examples.js');
Ext.application({        
    requires: [                    
        'Ext.window.MessageBox',
    'Ext.examples.*' 
    ],
```

i wonder if i have added the correct path above. The project structure is as follows;

```
Project_Folder
-> app.js
-> extjs
  --> examples
     --->shared
         ---->example.js
```

**UPDATE**

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.examples', '/Project_Folder/app/extjs/examples/shared/');
Ext.application({        
    requires: [                  
           'Ext.window.MessageBox',  
        'Ext.example.*' 
    ],
```

Comment: You have to give path without filename to setPath method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. but i still get the error `TypeError: Ext.example is undefined`. I have updated my code above.

Comment: try including the example.js file directly using <script> tag

Comment: No, still it says Ext.example is undefined. any clue ?

Comment: Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ?