# How to use a file from Ext.example

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I went through [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api) to find for a `Ext.example.msg` but, i am unable to find it.

According to this example, they have successfully used `Ext.example.msg`. How is this ?

I had another question on SO which is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975911/set-path-in-ext-js-typeerror-ext-example-is-undefined#comment15976840_11975911).

**UPDATE**

I am trying to use the following code in my application;

```
Ext.example.msg('Button Click', 'You clicked ta button');
```

When i execute the code, i get an error saying `TypeError: Ext.example is undefined` .

To overcome this error i did the following;

1.) added `<script type="text/javascript" src="app/extjs/examples/shared/examples.js"/>` in my app.html file

2.) added the following in my app.js file

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.example', 'app/extjs/examples/shared');

Ext.require(['Ext.container.Viewport',
'Ext.example.*']
);
```

None of the above methods works, i still get the same error message.

My project folder structure is as follows;

```
Project_Name
->app (folder)
--> app.html
--> app.js
--> extjs
  ---> examples
     ---->shared
         ----->example.js
```

Comment: The question is very unclear, and neither what you are trying to do nor your problem can be deducted. Your docs link refer to the general api docs, not to a specific section within it. Could you possibly improve your question?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: With syntax like `Ext.<class>.<method>` certain object methods are invoked. In your example you should have `Ext.example` class defined and you are trying to invoke `msg()` method of this class.

Comment: What do you mean, could you show me an example ?

Comment: Yes, but i still did not understand what you said.

Comment: And are you inserting ExtJS files correctly in your HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include your js script in you index.html, as you did in 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/extjs/examples/shared/examples.js"/>
```

You no longer need loader or to require it - you have explicitly included it and it is clear the script content will be in scope.

It appear to me your path is incorrect: There's no `app/extjs` and it would make sense to have the `extjs` folder as sibling to that of your app. Thus this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/examples/shared/examples.js"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, i have made a mistake in the Project structure. i have updated my question above.

Comment: OK, I take it your browser does not complain about not finding `examples.js`, did you include it **before** any script that might be using it, like `app.js`?

Comment: I inserted it after including app.js. When i include it before app.js the application doesn't work.

Comment: Well, if app.js users Ext.example, but its inclusion comes after the inclusion of app.js - you will get the undefined message. Why doesn't it work if you include it before? Surely because there's problem with including that file (incorrect path) thus app.js doesn't load, what does the browser complain about?

Comment: Yes, now i get it (the pop-up) but, i also get an error `TypeError: me.dd is undefined  me.dd.endDrag();`. I have also included the css file, but i still get the error.

Comment: Well, the me.dd is a different issue. I'd recommend you check which part of your code cause this. Must be something to do with how your scripts are (possibly dynamically). I'd post a new question on this one.

Comment: Yes, i will post a new question, but this error occurs only after the popup appears. So it has to be something to do with the example.js file.

Comment: It's hard to tell, whether me refer to the message box or to another part of your code. It would help to see exactly which line raise the error. Do you know how to look at the call stack? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Thank you, i have resolved it. But could you tell me how to look at the call stack. i am not aware of how to do it ?

Comment: That depends on which browser you work with. Firefox (with Firebug) or Chrome are highly recommended. I use Chrome - you just open the developer tools, when there's a JS error you see it on the console and if you click on it, it will show you the call stack.