# EXTJS4: Ext.msg Box ist not shown, throws an error

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4, messagebox

I simply want to show a MessageBox. But I get an error: TypeError: Ext.Msg is not a function

My code in the controller:

```
..... Ext.MessageBox.show({
                            title:'Delete',
                            msg: 'Delete user <b>'+r.extraParams.username+'</b>',
                            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
                            fn: function(buttonId) {
                                var userId=r.extraParams.userId;
                                console.log(buttonId);
                                if (buttonId === "yes") {
                                    Ext.Msg('OK', 'User deleted', 'success');
                                }
                            },
                            icon: Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION,

                        });....
```

It should be look like here, after you clicked a button: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/message-box/msg-box.html
Then a Message Box on the top of your Browser appears! Waht is wrong? Any ideas? THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a 'Ext.Msg is not a function' error because Ext.Msg isn't a function. See the documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox

So Ext.Msg is used incorrectly here:

```
if (buttonId === "yes") {
    Ext.Msg('OK', 'User deleted', 'success');
}
```

You'll have to show a new box:

```
if (buttonId === "yes") {
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Success',
        msg: 'User Deleted',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK 
    });
}
```

---

Edit: from your comments, it sounds like you want a confirmation box to appear and fade out. That's a bit trickier. Looking at their example:

```
Ext.get('mb4').on('click', function(e) {
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
      title: 'Save Changes?',
      msg: 'You are closing a tab that has unsaved changes. <br />Would you like to save your changes?',
      buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNOCANCEL,
      fn: showResult,
    });
  });

  function showResult(btn) {
    Ext.example.msg('Button Click', 'You clicked the {0} button', btn);
  };
```

They're calling some function they created for their examples called 'Ext.example.msg()'. It's not a common ExtJS component. You'll have to look in the ExtJS source for how they're using Ext.example.msg() if you wanted to copy that.

Here's a post on Ext forums asking the same thing: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?40261-Where-can-I-find-Ext.example.msg

Comment: But i don't want the normale MessageBox with Buttons. There is a kind of MessageBox as shown in the example on http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/message-box/msg-box.html. After you click a button in the normal messagebox, a new ohne appera on the top of the browser, and disappears after 1 second. And exactly this messagebox I want!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your application's js files. You miss something in extjs project. 
 [Here's same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986519/how-to-use-a-file-from-ext-example).